# Win32 C++ Programming. Converting Input Text to a separate .txt file

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a simple Win32 Program created that displays two text edit boxes, and one button that says convert.

The idea is that the user is supposed to input a series of numbers in the left box, and right box, then it should output a `.txt` file that matches the first row with the first row on the each box. I hope that is making sense I will try to explain graphically:

```
Edit Box One:  |       Edit Box 2:       |       Seperate .txt file (saved on desktop)


111            |    222                  |        111,222   
222            |    333                  |        222,333
```

As you can see that is my ultimate goal, I can add the code here:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define IDC_BUTTON_ONE                      101
#define IDC_EDITOR_BOX_EAST_WEST            102
#define IDC_EDITOR_BOX_NORTH_SOUTH          103

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
WNDCLASSEX wClassEx;
ZeroMemory(&wClassEx, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wClassEx.cbClsExtra = NULL;
wClassEx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wClassEx.cbWndExtra = NULL;
wClassEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
wClassEx.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInst, IDC_ARROW);
wClassEx.hIcon = NULL;
wClassEx.hIconSm = NULL;
wClassEx.hInstance = hInst;
wClassEx.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
wClassEx.lpszClassName = "Window Class";
wClassEx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wClassEx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wClassEx))
{
    int nResult = GetLastError();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Class creation failed", "CLASS CREATION FAILURE",    MB_ICONERROR);
}

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "Window Class", "Well Path Survey Convertor to Readable AutoCAD .SCR", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 200, 600, 490, NULL,
    NULL, hInst, NULL);
if (!hWnd)
{
    int nResult = GetLastError();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window creation failed", "WINDOW CREATION FAILURE", MB_ICONERROR);
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

MSG msg;
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

while (GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
                  HWND hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "Button",    "Click to Convert", WS_TABSTOP|WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                      200, 370, 150, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON_ONE, NULL, NULL);

                  HWND hEditEW = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", "", WS_CHILD|ES_MULTILINE| WS_VISIBLE |
                      ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 25, 50, 220, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDITOR_BOX_EAST_WEST, NULL, NULL);

                  HWND hEditNS = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", "", WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE |
                      ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 300, 50, 220, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDITOR_BOX_EAST_WEST, NULL, NULL);
}
    break;

case WM_COMMAND:
{
                   switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                   {
                   case IDC_BUTTON_ONE:
                   {


                   }

                       break;
                   }
                   break;
}

case WM_DESTROY:
{
                   PostQuitMessage(0);
                   return 0;
}
    break;
}
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: What are you having problems with?  Choosing a filename?  Opening the file?  Getting the strings from the textboxes?  Writing strings to a file?

Comment: No just where to begin, I have the skeleton for the command set up when I hit the "convert" button, but as for the syntax I don't even know where to begin. How to compare the two boxes to output a single file

Comment: Well, my above comment gives you the four steps you need to accomplish.

Comment: Can you please give me a direction where to search for help for that. How too choose a filename, how to compare the strings from the textboxes, and how to write the strings to a file. Please

Comment: I can tell you how to make a unique filename, but it won't look nice and if it's on the user's desktop, they will see it and be unhappy.  So what do *you* think the filenames should look like?  Also, `SHGetFolderPath` will help you find the desktop so you can create files there.  And see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17933917/103167

Comment: Choosing a filename is up to you - why not start with "c:\test.txt" and later allow the user to enter a filename? Googling for "open file", "compare strings" and "write text to file" would be a good way of starting to learn about the other points.

Comment: Ok I am making some headway on this task, I am facing a problem on the WriteFile(); function the second argument asks for a pointer to the buffer that is storing the information. what Syntax do I use to point the input text from the boxes?