# create desktop file getting %userprofile%?

Tags: c

I want to get the desktop dir folder, so I tried:

```
  char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  char newLocation[]="%userprofile%\\desktop\\myfile.exe";
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  CopyFile(filename, newLocation, stats);
```

%userprofile% is not working. how can I get the user profile path?

Comment: I think this link can halp you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933917/get-the-users-desktop-folder-using-windows-api

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this other answers will help:

https://superuser.com/questions/571974/userprofile-variable-not-working

or:

https://superuser.com/questions/442158/why-cant-i-use-userprofile-in-path

You can type:

```
set
```

In a command prompt you will get a list of all environment variables defined on your system.

Comment: thank you for your answer! yeah, I think in C I cannot use %userprofile% or %windir%... i will check this links!

Comment: So maybe this will be more helpfull?(C++)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827496/how-to-properly-use-userprofile-inside-code